# Setting up access point for more than 100 smart devices

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration

I have 100 smart devices trying to send around 1-3KB data every 1 min. All the devices are placed in a single room. How should I set up my access point so that the devices can reliably send data to the server?

Comment: What makes you think it requires any specific configuration change?  Your question isn't detailed enough to answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound I have an AC1900 ASUS router and I see that the smart devices are getting disconnected periodically.

Comment: Are we sure it's not the fault of these devices?

Answer (score 0):

If you have traffic manager in your AC1900 ASUS GUI/WMI (Graphical User Interface / Web Management Interface) - Click it, enable QoS and set the traffic threshold you'd like.  In your case, allow 5KB of traffic per device.  This will guarantee that there are no bandwidth hoggers on your wireless network.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your problem isn't bandwidth per se (obviously). It's that you only have one "traffic lane" doing the job of ten. Nice router btw... I have the next model down for my home network.

Here's the biggest problem: Wifi is half-duplex (unlike ethernet which is full duplex). Only one device, including the router, can transmit at any one time... the rest have to stop and listen. They take turns. Normally this works great cause data flow happens mostly in one direction, from the router to a device (think watching a movie or music or even browsing the web).

With a hundred and one devices (the router counts) each sending and receiving small amounts of data many times per minute your WiFi bandwidth is effectively cut in half. And really it's more like 200 devices... cause the router gets a turn every time another device finishes its turn. You still, probably, have enough bandwidth even accounting for overhead and the like but not as much as the box claims you do. So your usage pattern is actually eating up bandwidth faster than what is conventional considered "heavy usage".

But the real problem only shows itself during "traffic jams." It's not that your highway/wifi, on a given day/second, can't handle the number of cars/bytes on it... it's that it can't handle them all right this minute/millisecond when they want it to.

So what's likely happening is mostly things are fine but eventually multiple devices need access at the same time, so they get in line. But then, by the time the router clears its queue, it happens again. Now sometimes the router will catch up... but eventually, it will happen enough times to overwhelm the router. So the line gets longer, and longer... a wave of latency propagating backward. Eventually, some devices have to wait long enough that they decided it isn't worth it disconnect to search for another network.

Normally in an office environment or public space (where lots of WiFi devices are expected), I would install dozens of access points each connected to the central switch via ethernet thus keeping the number of devices any one AP is responsible for to a minimum. The APs would also operate on slightly different channels from their closest peers so as to limit interference. The goal would be for 25-30 devices per access point... though, again, this is with enterprise grade gear.

A hundred devices on a single consumer grade AP is "bug nuts". And even if you could solve the problem with the WiFi end of it, the actual router portion of your router isn't designed to be routing that many devices. It's poor little, integrated CPU and tiny little RAM chips, massive though they may be compared to other consumer grade products, are not sufficient to handle the kind of traffic you are talking about. The key detail here: it's not how much bandwidth you use... it's how many separate routes the device has to keep track of at a given time. That central switch I mentioned above? That would be an enterprise grade unit mounted in a rack with something equivalent to or possibly even better than the CPU in your computer. Possibly more than one of them. Then an enterprise grade gateway appliance providing internet connectivity.

What you are trying to accomplish isn't ever going to be 100% reliable. I'm sorry, I love my little ASUS router and look forward to buying it's younger, beefier brother when I can spare the coin... but it's still not designed for the kind of work load you are throwing at it.